# how to select TOP 5 but excluding some results (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So I have this code..

```
SELECT TOP 5 Student_ID,
CASE
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 >= 96.5 THEN '4.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 92.4 THEN '3.5'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 88.4 THEN '3.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 84.4 THEN '2.5'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 79.4 THEN '2.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 74.4 THEN '1.5'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 69.4 THEN '1.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 < 69.5 THEN 'R'
ELSE ''
END AS 'GPA'
FROM Grades
GROUP BY Student_ID
ORDER BY GPA DESC
```

This is the result:

```
Student_ID | GPA   
 200128       R
 200122      3.5
 200126      3.5
 200120      3.0
 200125      3.0
```

How can I exclude the student with the GPA  'R' when getting the TOP 5?

Answer (score 4):

Change the `order by`:

```
ORDER BY (case when GPA = 'R' then 2 else 1 end),
         GPA DESC
```

You could also do:

```
ORDER BY SUM(Grade)/5 DESC
```

This is subtly different, because the first way will treat all students with the same "GPA" as equal.  This will order them (under the covers) by the numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Add a having clause:

```
GROUP BY Student_ID
HAVING SUM(Grade) <> 'R' --Or some other criteria
ORDER BY GPA DESC
```

Comment: You can not refer to alias in having clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 5 Student_ID,
CASE
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 >= 96.5 THEN '4.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 92.4 THEN '3.5'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 88.4 THEN '3.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 84.4 THEN '2.5'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 79.4 THEN '2.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 74.4 THEN '1.5'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 > 69.4 THEN '1.0'
    WHEN SUM(Grade)/5 < 69.5 THEN 'R'
ELSE ''
END AS 'GPA'
FROM Grades
GROUP BY Student_ID
HAVING SUM(Grade)/5 >= 69.5
ORDER BY GPA DESC
```